# blazor-wasm httpclient calls windows authentication enabled web-api

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, windows-authentication, blazor-webassembly

1. Web-Api "app A" is IIS hosted on a server A with Windows Authentication enabled. Enabled CORS like this.

```html
<httpProtocol>
       <customHeaders>
       <clear />
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

2. blaozr-webasm app is IIS hosted, on a server B with windows authentication. So that Domain authenticated users can launch this app.

Scenario is Blazor-wasm has to consume the web-API app A.  we cannot set the HttpClientHandler credentials property, as it not supported on the browser platfor. (UnsupportedOSPlatform("browser"))

> Error - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (unauthorized)

How to make calls succeed from blazor-wasm to windows authentication enabled web-api "app A".

Comment: The main config would be [on IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) on Server A.